# C# - how do I find a key value inside an enum with a property?

Tags: c#

Given the C# enum:

```
public enum options: byte
{
    yes = 0,
    no = 22,
    maybe = 62,
    foscho = 42
}
```

How do you retrieve the String 'maybe' if given the byte 62?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enum value to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120436/enum-value-to-string)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cast int to enum in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482/cast-int-to-enum-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can cast it to enum and retreive by `ToString()`:

```
var result = ((options)62).ToString();
```

Comment: Works, but please don't do it this way. This is bad-practice, don't teach yourself bad-practice. Exceptions will be thrown when a specific value doesn't match the enum. 

You should use Enum.GetName or Enum.TryParse.

Comment: @It'sme...Alex nope - no exception will be thrown - the int value will be returned, when there is no matching enum value.

Comment: WTF?! You're right ... this is Sooooo bad. Casting a non-existing value to an enum actually works. Don't know whether this is behavior that everyone likes ... I dont. For me it would be one more reason to prefer GetName (or TryParse when a values comes in as a string) above casting

Comment: Yeah - it's good interview question - "What happens if you cast int to non-existing enum value?" :)

Answer (score 4):

`var stringValue = Enum.GetName(typeof(options), 62);    // returns "maybe"`

Which you might also want to wrap in a check:

```
if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(options), 62))
{
    var stringValue = Enum.GetName(typeof(options), 62);    // returns "maybe"`
}
```

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Could the down-voter please explain what they didn't like about my answer?